# Is this a grammatical sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

I found the following sentence without any context and it sounds ungrammatical but I can't for the life of me understand why. Would someone be willing to explain if it is or isn't grammatical and why?

"It is how companies work."

Answer (score 4):

The sentence is grammatical and can be paraphrased "that is the way companies operate".

**It** here would refer back to something which has been mentioned earlier in the conversation that forms the context of this sentence.

"It is how" = that is the manner in which

companies work = companies operate/function

For example

> Two thousand people lost their jobs and the physical assets of the
>   plant were sold off. The company had been in operation for over sixty
>   years!
>   --It is how publicly traded corporations work in capitalist countries: shareholder interests are supreme. The short-term interests of the shareholders were given greater priority than the long-term interests of the workers and the community.